# How can I get an element's width in px in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Since the element can vary its width depending on the content it has, I don't know how to get its width in px.

Here is the basic, simplified, structure:

```
// React component 

export const Navbar = ({ month }) => (
  <NavbarStyled>
    <div>
      <span>{month}</span>  //month is what varies in width
    </div>
  </NavbarStyled>
)
```

```
// NavbarStyled.js

export const NavbarStyled = styled.nav`
  ...

  span:after{
    ...  

    animation: show 1s ease forwards;
  }

  @keyframes show{
    100%{
      transform: translateX(the_element's_width_in_px);
    }
  }
`
```

I've tried a lot of things with no results.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What happens when you use the value 100%?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the width by using the [getBoundingClientRect() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which will return an object of the element's attributes.
With styled components, you will need to reference the element using the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook [or another referencing method](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in order to call getBoundingClientRect().

```
referencedElement.getBoundingClientRect()
// Return the width by calling referencedElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Comment: just a little addition - `referencedElement.current.getBoundingClientRect()` :)